# Best way to read yahoo IMAP emails using with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, api, yahoo

What is the best way to read yahoo IMAP emails using with C#?

I searched many places for that, but as you know yahoo changes it's web site every minute and finding a non deprecated library is difficult.

Also found non-free Lib [here](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=3).

Would you please suggest me free ways to just read Yahoo mails using with C#?

Comment: Three downvotes is not fair, you should downvote yahoo because they open close their services....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 protocols that are used to send and receive emails:

1. SMTP
2. POP3
3. IMAP

*SMTP* is used to send emails and *IMAP* and *POP3* are used to receive mails.

So in your case you can simply use an *IMAP* library to connect to the yahoo servers and grab all mails.

I recommend you to use [*IMAPX*](https://imapx.codeplex.com/)
There is a very good [documentation](https://imapx.codeplex.com/documentation) and you should find various examples on google.

A simple connection that downloads all mail messages in the inbox would look like the following:

```
var client = new ImapX.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
client.Connection();
client.LogIn(userName, userPassword);
var messages = client.Folders["INBOX"].Search("ALL", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImapX2 ( crossplatform IMAP library for .NET )

ImapX 2 is a crossplatform IMAP library for .NET, supporting SSL/TLS, Idle, OAuth2 and all major GMail IMAP extensions. It's the only IMAP library which supports all .Net 2.0 - 4.5, Mono and Windows Phone 7.1 and 8.0.

What is [IMAP](http://www.kompyooter.com/?qa=134/what-are-smtp-pop3-and-imap) ,Find yahoo samples [here](https://imapx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ImapX.Sample/Yahoo/YahooOAuth2Provider.cs)